# ¿Como asignar escuchas en java mvc desktop con varios formularios?

Tags: java, mvc

Buenas tardes comunidad

Estoy desarrollando un sistema de ventas en java con mvc y hibernate. y se presenta un problema, a la hora de acceder al formulario principal despues de el login, no me toma en cuenta los escuchas y no me permite abrir los siguientes formularios

### [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

me toma los escuchas del login sin problemas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

en el formulario principal ya no toma ningun escucha

---

```
package vista;

import controlador.ControladorPrincipal;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class frmPrincipal extends javax.swing.JFrame {

public frmPrincipal() {
    initComponents();
}

public void AsignarEscuchas(ControladorPrincipal c) {
    lblAdministracion.addMouseListener(c);
    lblAdministracionBarra.addMouseListener(c);
}

public JLabel getLblAdministracion() {
    return lblAdministracion;
}

public void setLblAdministracion(JLabel lblAdministracion) {
    this.lblAdministracion = lblAdministracion;
}

public JLabel getLblAdministracionBarra() {
    return lblAdministracionBarra;
}

public void setLblAdministracionBarra(JLabel lblAdministracionBarra) {
    this.lblAdministracionBarra = lblAdministracionBarra;
}

public JLabel getLblAdministracionImagen() {
    return lblAdministracionImagen;
}

public void setLblAdministracionImagen(JLabel lblAdministracionImagen) {
    this.lblAdministracionImagen = lblAdministracionImagen;
}

public JLabel getLblAyuda() {
    return lblAyuda;
}

public void setLblAyuda(JLabel lblAyuda) {
    this.lblAyuda = lblAyuda;
}

public JLabel getLblAyudaBarra() {
    return lblAyudaBarra;
}

public void setLblAyudaBarra(JLabel lblAyudaBarra) {
    this.lblAyudaBarra = lblAyudaBarra;
}

public JLabel getLblAyudaImagen() {
    return lblAyudaImagen;
}

public void setLblAyudaImagen(JLabel lblAyudaImagen) {
    this.lblAyudaImagen = lblAyudaImagen;
}

public JLabel getLblClientes() {
    return lblClientes;
}

public void setLblClientes(JLabel lblClientes) {
    this.lblClientes = lblClientes;
}

public JLabel getLblClientesBarra() {
    return lblClientesBarra;
}

public void setLblClientesBarra(JLabel lblClientesBarra) {
    this.lblClientesBarra = lblClientesBarra;
}

public JLabel getLblClientesImagen() {
    return lblClientesImagen;
}

public void setLblClientesImagen(JLabel lblClientesImagen) {
    this.lblClientesImagen = lblClientesImagen;
}

public JLabel getLblCompras() {
    return lblCompras;
}

public void setLblCompras(JLabel lblCompras) {
    this.lblCompras = lblCompras;
}

public JLabel getLblComprasBarra() {
    return lblComprasBarra;
}

public void setLblComprasBarra(JLabel lblComprasBarra) {
    this.lblComprasBarra = lblComprasBarra;
}

public JLabel getLblComprasImagen() {
    return lblComprasImagen;
}

public void setLblComprasImagen(JLabel lblComprasImagen) {
    this.lblComprasImagen = lblComprasImagen;
}

public JLabel getLblInicio() {
    return lblInicio;
}

public void setLblInicio(JLabel lblInicio) {
    this.lblInicio = lblInicio;
}

public JLabel getLblProductos() {
    return lblProductos;
}

public void setLblProductos(JLabel lblProductos) {
    this.lblProductos = lblProductos;
}

public JLabel getLblProductosBarra() {
    return lblProductosBarra;
}

public void setLblProductosBarra(JLabel lblProductosBarra) {
    this.lblProductosBarra = lblProductosBarra;
}

public JLabel getLblProductosImagen() {
    return lblProductosImagen;
}

public void setLblProductosImagen(JLabel lblProductosImagen) {
    this.lblProductosImagen = lblProductosImagen;
}

public JLabel getLblProveedores() {
    return lblProveedores;
}

public void setLblProveedores(JLabel lblProveedores) {
    this.lblProveedores = lblProveedores;
}

public JLabel getLblProveedoresBarra() {
    return lblProveedoresBarra;
}

public void setLblProveedoresBarra(JLabel lblProveedoresBarra) {
    this.lblProveedoresBarra = lblProveedoresBarra;
}

public JLabel getLblProveedoresImagen() {
    return lblProveedoresImagen;
}

public void setLblProveedoresImagen(JLabel lblProveedoresImagen) {
    this.lblProveedoresImagen = lblProveedoresImagen;
}

public JLabel getLblReportes() {
    return lblReportes;
}

public void setLblReportes(JLabel lblReportes) {
    this.lblReportes = lblReportes;
}

public JLabel getLblReportesBarra() {
    return lblReportesBarra;
}

public void setLblReportesBarra(JLabel lblReportesBarra) {
    this.lblReportesBarra = lblReportesBarra;
}

public JLabel getLblReportesImagen() {
    return lblReportesImagen;
}

public void setLblReportesImagen(JLabel lblReportesImagen) {
    this.lblReportesImagen = lblReportesImagen;
}

public JLabel getLblVentas() {
    return lblVentas;
}

public void setLblVentas(JLabel lblVentas) {
    this.lblVentas = lblVentas;
}

public JLabel getLblVentasBarra() {
    return lblVentasBarra;
}

public void setLblVentasBarra(JLabel lblVentasBarra) {
    this.lblVentasBarra = lblVentasBarra;
}

public JLabel getLblVentasImagen() {
    return lblVentasImagen;
}

public void setLblVentasImagen(JLabel lblVentasImagen) {
    this.lblVentasImagen = lblVentasImagen;
}
```

---

```
 package controlador;

import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import vista.frmAdministracion;
import vista.frmPrincipal;

public class ControladorPrincipal implements MouseListener {

private frmPrincipal vista;

public ControladorPrincipal(frmPrincipal vista) {
    this.vista = vista;
}

@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    if (e.getSource() == vista.getLblAdministracion() || e.getSource() == vista.getLblAdministracionBarra()
            || e.getSource() == vista.getLblAdministracionImagen()) {
        frmAdministracion frm = new frmAdministracion();
        frm.show();
    }
}

@Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {

}

@Override
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {

}

@Override
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {

}

@Override
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {

}
```

}

---

```
package principal;

import controlador.ControladorLogin;
import controlador.ControladorPrincipal;
import controlador.ControladorRegistro;
import modeloDAO.LoginDAO;
import modeloDAO.UsuarioDAO;
import vista.frmAdministracion;
import vista.frmLogin;
import vista.frmPrincipal;
import vista.frmRegistro;

public class principal {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    frmLogin frmlogin = new frmLogin();
    frmPrincipal frmprincipal = new frmPrincipal();
    frmRegistro frmregistro = new frmRegistro();

    LoginDAO modeloLoginDAO = new LoginDAO();
    UsuarioDAO modeloUsuarioDAO = new UsuarioDAO();

    ControladorLogin controladorLogin = new ControladorLogin(frmlogin, modeloLoginDAO);
    ControladorPrincipal controladorPrincipal = new ControladorPrincipal(frmprincipal);
    ControladorRegistro controladorRegistro = new ControladorRegistro(modeloUsuarioDAO, frmregistro);

    frmlogin.AsignarEscuchas(controladorLogin);
    frmprincipal.AsignarEscuchas(controladorPrincipal);
    frmregistro.AsignarEscuchas(controladorRegistro);

    frmlogin.setVisible(true);

}
```

}

Comment: `escuchas`? Quieres decir `listeners`?

Comment: En todo caso, los nombres de la clase siempre deben empezar por mayúscula y los de métodos, variables y package deben empezar por minúscula.

Comment: muchas gracias amigo siempre olvido aplicar el camelcase modificare eso ^^ si me refiero a los listeners

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontré la solución al problema ^^

Tocaba crear una instancia de la clase frmAdministracion, ControladorAdministracion y hacer visible el formulario

los escuchas ya no los asigno en la vista sino en el controlador

```
 package controlador;

 import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
 import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
 import vista.frmAdministracion;
 import vista.frmPrincipal;

public class ControladorPrincipal implements MouseListener {

private frmPrincipal vista;

public ControladorPrincipal(frmPrincipal vista) {
    this.vista = vista;
    AsignarEscuchas();
}

public void AsignarEscuchas() {
    vista.getLblAdministracion().addMouseListener(this);
    vista.getLblAdministracionBarra().addMouseListener(this);
    vista.getLblAdministracionImagen().addMouseListener(this);
}

@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    if (e.getSource() == vista.getLblAdministracion() || e.getSource() == vista.getLblAdministracionBarra()
            || e.getSource() == vista.getLblAdministracionImagen()) {
        frmAdministracion frm = new frmAdministracion();
        ControladorAdministracion control= new ControladorAdministracion(frm);         
        frm.setVisible(true);
    }
}

@Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {

}

@Override
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {

}

@Override
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {

}

@Override
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {

}
```

}